# boost::spirit: iterator and parsing for multidimensional input

Tags: c++, parsing, iterator, boost-spirit

The input for the parser is similar to this example:

```
struct Word{
    Word(std::string txt, int val)
    :text(txt)
    ,value(val)
    {}

    std::string text;
    int value;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Word> input;

    input.push_back(Word("This", 10));
    input.push_back(Word("is", 73));
    input.push_back(Word("the", 5));
    input.push_back(Word("input", 32));
}
```

The grammar for the parser is written for to the `text` variable of the Words and can look like this:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, int()> word = qi::string("This") | 
                                 qi::string("is") | 
                                 qi::string("the") | 
                                 qi::string("input"); 
qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<int>()> start = +word;
```

Parsing the `std::vector<Word> input` should result in a vector containing the corresponding Integer values, for this example it would be

```
[10,73,5,32]
```

1. Is this even possible with boost::spirit or should I take a different approach?

If this is could be a reasonable solution,

2. How can one implement an `Iterator` for this, how does it look like?
3. What should the semantic actions look like to create the corresponding synthesized attribute or do I need some other spirit "magic"?

I hope I have provided enough information for this, let me know if not.

---

EDIT:

Looks like I asked not specific enough since I tried to keep this question as general as possible. [Sehe's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125093/boostspirit-iterator-and-parsing-for-multidimensional-input/29132076#29132076) should work for what I described, but I have the following limitations:

1. A Word can occur multiple times with different Integer values, there is no correlation between a Words text and its Integer value
2. The "text" (in this example "This is the input") needs to be parsed anyway to complete another task. I have already written everything to do so and it would be really easy for me to add what I need, if only I could access the Integer value from inside the semantic actions somehow.

Answer (score 1):

This appears superficially more related to lexing (a.k.a. tokenizing or scanning). See Boost Spirit Lex.

With Spirit Qi "magic", use symbols:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b61e4604f8013ffd)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

struct tokens : qi::symbols<char, int>
{
    tokens() {
        add
            ("This",  10)
            ("is",    73)
            ("the",   5)
            ("input", 32);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::string const input("This is the input");

    std::vector<int> parsed;
    std::string::const_iterator f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, qi::no_case[ +tokens() ], qi::space, parsed);

    if (ok)
        std::cout << "Parse success: ";
    else
        std::cout << "Parse failed: ";

    std::copy(parsed.begin(), parsed.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "\nRemaining input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
Parse success: 10 73 5 32
```

See also **[`qi::no_case`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/no_case.html)** and **[`qi::symbols`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/string/symbols.html)**:

> *When `symbols` is used for case-insensitive parsing (in a `no_case` directive), added symbol strings should be in lowercase. Symbol strings containing one or more uppercase characters will not match any input when symbols is used in a `no_case` directive.*

Comment: Thx for the fast response. However, this is not exactly the direction I was thinking about (should have been more specific in my question). I added more detail to my question, can it be done the way I described (iterating through `Word` and access from inside the semantic actions)?

Comment: Hrmm. So. What exactly do you want? _"Parsing the `std::vector<Word>` input"_ makes exactly zero sense. Text is parsed. Objects are traversed. Pick one. But since you mention [tag:boost-spirit] as well as [tag:parsing] forgive me for assuming you... actually wanted to parse something

Comment: Maybe lets put it that way: There is a text which needs to be parsed (result from speech recognition). For every word in this text there is an additional value (Integer in this case), representing the probability that this word was recognised correctly. While parsing the text to check if it is a valid statement, I would like to somehow access the additional (Integer) value for the current word to construct a custom synthesised attribute. I hope this at least clarifies what my goal is. I just have no idea how this could be done.

Comment: Ahaaaa. Now you're making sense. You should consider making the input tuples _(raw token, confidence)_  a token iterator. Usually these are obtained from calling `tokenenize` (or `tokenize_and_parse`) on a set of token definitions (the lexer). How many _distinct_ potential tokens do you anticipate?

Comment: The number of distinct potential tokens is defined at runtime and theoretically has no limits. However, 50-100, maybe sometimes up to 200 could be realistic. The input would be a sentence with approximately 10-30 different words. I'm not sure if I understood the concept of a lexer correctly, but what would happen if there are multiple instances of the same word(token) with different confidences in a sentence?

Comment: That's not what I'm getting at. Of course I understand that the confidence will vary per instance of a matched word. I was trying to establish whether you need one token definition or one per expected token (and you've answered that). I'll mull this over a bit